# Life cycle methods to kill an app?

Tags: android

I'm doing a simple game, and I'm using onPause and onResume. But I have a problem, when I start the game again, after I have left it with the main button on the phone(I'm using android 2.3.6) it's just as it was before I left it! Do I also need onDestroy? Or should "kill" the game in some other way? Preciate som help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android handles multitasking by backgrounding your applications. The app shouldn't exit when you press the home button. So your users will expect that the app is **not killed** and stays the same when they resume it (just like what happens now).

If you do want to kill your app anyway, then add the following to your Activities' `onPause` method:

```
System.exit (0);
```